# How can I make sure _gaq.push() works good?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Our client asked us to implement the following Google Analytic code:

```
_gaq.push(['SX0._setCustomVar', 4, 'xxxx', "yyyy", 2]);
```

So I've made this, and now I'm looking for a way - how can I check that everything is correct (without actually building GA report)? I haven't did this before - so please sorry if the answer is obvious.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to define the _gaq variable and load in the analytics script from googles server. After that, you should be able to call the 'push' method.

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();


// tracks hit for /some/page/
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/some/page']);
```

After that's done, load up the page in your browser, open up the console, and look in the network tab. Try loading a few pages, and verify that it's asynchronously pushing data to googles servers.

Google uses a .gif image for tracking, so you might try filtering by image and to find request for a file called __utm.gif

[image]

If you're still having trouble finding it, you might try the [tag debugger plugin by ObservePoint for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/observepoint-tag-debugger/daejfbkjipkgidckemjjafiomfeabemo?hl=en-US) or the [Official Tag assistant plugin by Google](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you for answer - but this code is already exists. Now I've made my modifications - and how can I ensure that it is working/tracking well? Does it send some async requests which I can see in browser console or somethign like that?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly right. I've updated my answer. Take a look in the network tab and look for communication with googles servers on page load.

Comment: I've tried to find something but communication history is too large - can you give me an example of that request? Or something that I can use to filter network requests?

Comment: Try filtering by image and look for a request for a file called __utm.gif http://i.imgur.com/vQYwudN.png

Comment: If you're having trouble finding it, you could also try the ObservePoint tag debugger. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/observepoint-tag-debugger/daejfbkjipkgidckemjjafiomfeabemo?hl=en-US

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Analytics debugger extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) for Chrome. Another useful extension (although it will not help you with custom vars) is the [Google Tag Assistant](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk?hl=en) (which will also check other Google tags such as adwords conversion tags and the like).